# meaning of the adverb "questionably" in context

Tags: meaning

The sentence with the adverb is from [Crash Course Anatomy & Phisiology](https://youtu.be/pqgcEIaXGME). It is at around 21 second. Here is the context:

> In fact, Beaumond performed so many surgeries on the injury  over the next several months, that he decided, somewhat **questionably**, to just keep St. Martin's stomach wound open.

Does that mean that the surgeon's decision not to stich the wound kind of immoral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His decision to do X was somewhat **questionable**.   <sup>adjective</sup>

He decided, somewhat **questionably**, to do X.   <sup>adverb</sup>

One would have reasonable grounds to **question** the decision, somewhat. <sup>verb</sup>

**to question** in this sense means to ask whether a course of action was appropriate. With **somewhat**, it means to do so in a manner that only borders on an accusation that the person was acting with poor judgment when taking that action. The word **somewhat** is a hedge.  It's not an accusation outright.

Comment: It might be worth [pointing out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=questionably%2Cunquestionably&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquestionably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunquestionably%3B%2Cc0) that the negated adverbial form is unquestionably more common. And to be honest, I can't see any easy way of idiomatically including the non-negated version in OP's cite context without also including the word ***somewhat*** (which is almost a kind of "weak negation" in itself).

Comment: His decision was not unquestionably questionable; it was only somewhat questionable. Somewhat is only somewhat a negation.

Comment: So you think it would only be *somewhat* difficult to rephrase OP's example in such a way as to retain ***questionably*** whilst discarding ***somewhat**?* I'm almost tempted to cancel my upvote and only reinstate it if/when you can come up with a credible rephrasing! :)

Comment: *He decided, questionably, to keep the wound open.*  is perfectly legit, though less likely in the 21st century than *He made the questionable decision to keep the wound open.*

Comment: He decided something somewhat questionably.  So, sure, we have an example of a questionable decision.  What we don't have (and what OP wants to know) are the grounds for the potential questions.  The decision might be questionable on ethical and moral grounds, or on legal grounds, or on purely practical ground, or on nearly any other basis that we can imagine.  Does "somewhat questionably" mean "somewhat morally questionably"?  Maybe.  Maybe not.

Comment: We ***unquestionably can*** use the negated form before the operative verb, but I can't easily imagine the non-negated form being used that way. And even if it comes *after* the verb, it's only really idiomatic if it's parenthetically set off by commas, as in your example. We are ***unquestionably led*** to the conclusion that the affordances of the negated form don't match those of the base form.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily immoral, but instead professionally unsound.  It could be considered a mistake, but it's not clear-cut.